# How assign value for variable inside "then"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, axios

```
    const testFunc = () => {
let test = [];
    axios
      .post('test.com', {
        filters: [
          {
            comparison: 'eq',
            fieldName: 'ID',
            fieldValue: `${id}`,
          },
        ],
      }).then(({ data }) => test = data);

return test;
}
```

I need to write to the variable what I get in the response, but the attempt to do this ends with nothing being written to the variable

Comment: Shouldn't the return be in side of `then`? else you are returning the test too early, as in before the promise is finished so test is still `[]`

Comment: This blog post of mine might also help thinking about this problem differently: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: But in short: `return axios......then(({data}) => data)` and later: `testFunc().then(data => console.log("look it's my data!", data))`.

Comment: @Huangism then I have to use async / await ?

Comment: the marked dupes will guide you to the holy grail